# using servlet,jsp login and regestration forms

Tags: jsp, servlets

Create a login and registration forms using Servlets and jsp without database using hashmap

Comment: using with servlet,jsp without database create a login & registration forms in ecalipse ide, with hashmap ....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: using servlet, jsp  first register with email , username , password. And=y  next login with registry details like username  password...without database .... without database we cant store the register details so using hashmap said by my  boss .....this is my one of the task given by my boss... using tools::ecalipse.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the POJO class of your needs and can create the HashMap like: (I take key in String, POJO class Person for login)

```
//Map Representation:  Map<String, List<Person>> personDetails = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

    class Person{
        private String name;
       //other variables

       //Setters and getters
        public void setName(String name){
              this.name = name;
         }

        public String getName(){
               return name;
         }
        }

    public class LoginDetails extends HttpServlet{

    Map<String, List<Person>> carDetails = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException
      {
          String name = request.getParameter("name");
          String uname = request.getParameter("uname");

          if(name != null && uname != null){
              Person p1 = new Person();
              p1.setName(name);
              personDetails.put(uname, p1); //This makes a primary key kind of //relation and makes a virtual database in memory. You can even //retrieve it easily using for loop.
    //You can do the same for the rest of your logic.
          }


      }

    }
```

This makes a structure like table in the database with the primary key. Hope this helps...!!!